# Entity Framework Volatile Isolation Level

Tags: entity-framework

I found the following description for the `Serializable` (`IsolationLevel.Serializable`) isolation level in the MSDN documentation:

> Volatile data can be read but not modified, and no new data can be added during the transaction.
>
> [(Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.isolationlevel.aspx)

And on the same page volatile data is defined as:

> The data affected by a transaction is called volatile.

My question is, how can I prevent other transactions from reading volatile data and also prevent them from adding any new data.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is highest isolation level you can get. According to this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) , this should be enough for your need.

> SERIALIZABLE Specifies the following: Statements cannot read data that
>   has been modified but not yet committed by other transactions. No
>   other transactions can modify data that has been read by the current
>   transaction until the current transaction completes. Other
>   transactions cannot insert new rows with key values that would fall in
>   the range of keys read by any statements in the current transaction
>   until the current transaction completes.